# SQL Server : queries for quantity

Tags: sql-server

**TABLE 1**

```
ID    |      DATE       |   
 a    |   10-07-2012    |     
 b    |   10-07-2012    |     
 c    |   10-07-2012    |
```

**TABLE2**

```
ID    |    OrdersID  |
 a    |     001      |
 b    |     002      |
 c    |     003      |
```

**TABLE3**

```
ItemID    |   OrdersID    |  Items |
    1     |     001       |   5    |  
    2     |     002       |   3    |  
    7     |     003       |   2    | 
    3     |     003       |   7    | 
    4     |     001       |   8    |
    2     |     003       |   7    |
    5     |     003       |   6    |   
    6     |     003       |   1    |
```

**TABLE4**

```
 ItemID   | ItemName   |  
    1     |  ABC       |
    2     |  EFG       |
    3     |  HIJ       |
    4     |  KLM       |
    5     |  NOP       |
    6     |  QRS       |
    7     |  TUV       |
```

I would like to select the ID's from `TABLE1` t where `Date = 10-07-2012`

In `Table2` with the ID's I would like to select the `OrdersID`'s

With the `OrdersID`'s I would like to add together how many Items of a `ItemID` exist e.g. `IteamID` 2 has a total of 10 Items

From `TABLE3` I would like to know the top 5 Items and the quantity of Items in Order and get the names of the the `ItemID` from `TABLLE4` `ItemName`.

Expected results 5 results

```
ItemID  |  ItemName  |  Quantity  | 
   2    |  EFG       |     10     | 
   3    |  HIJ       |      7     | 
      .....
  .....
      .....
      .....
```

SQL used at the start ...

```
 SELECT SUM (t3.Items) , t4.ItemName
  FROM Table3 t3
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON t3.OrdersID = t2.OrdersID
  JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
  WHERE t1.[Date] = '10072012 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to break ties in your top five, this is a working answer.

```
select top 5
    t3.ItemID,
    (select ItemName from TABLE4 as t4 where t4.ItemID = t3.ItemID) as ItemName,
    sum(t3.Items) as Quantity
from TABLE3 as t3
where t3.OrdersID in (
    select OrdersID
    from TABLE1 as t1 inner join TABLE2 as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
    where DATE = cast('20121007' as datetime)
)
group by t3.ItemID
order by Quantity desc
```

Here's the output I get. Notice that Item 4 ranks higher than Item 3 which does not match with the sample output specified.

```
ItemID | ItemName | Quantity  
   2   |    EFG   |    10  
   4   |    KLM   |     8  
   3   |    HIJ   |     7  
   5   |    NOP   |     6  
   1   |    ABC   |     5
```

Comment: I composed this solution as I made sense of your problem. Because of the way you described it, I broke it down in similar steps and then later realized that it really did only need a join from t2 to t3 as done in the other answer. The answers should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing a `GROUP BY` clause, and a `JOIN` into `Table4`. Your sample results also include `ItemID`, so I'll add that from `Table4` as well:

```
 SELECT 
   SUM(t3.Items) , 
   t4.ItemID, 
   t4.ItemName
 FROM 
   Table3 t3
   JOIN Table2 t2 ON t3.OrdersID = t2.OrdersID
   JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
   JOIN Table4 t4 ON t3.ItemID = t4.ItemID 
 WHERE t1.[Date] = '10072012 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY 
   t4.ItemID, 
   t4.ItemName
```